# Mirroring with differing refs GitHub to Gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-actions, action

**Problem**: If you're not an administrator of the Gitlab instance you do not have permission to use or enable *mirroring* or use *migration*.

**Question:** What are your options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the migration feature of gitlab works just fine. I simply had to create an api-token in github and import the github projects with proper credentials to gitlab with the given token.

Regarding your error message above, it seems like you have changes in your gitlab repository remotely already, which should not be the case when you create an empty repository.

What might help is to do the following:

- clone your github repository locally
- add your gitlab repository as alternating remote
- push your local repository to the alternating remote